# How to get the value of property expansion in groovy

Tags: web-services, groovy, soapui

Let's say I have this formula in a soap request

```
${test#Response#//ns1:authentification/bloc1/bloc2/idSession}
```

If next step I want to save this value in test case property using groovy, how can I get the runtime value ?

Or is it possible to do it without even using groovy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this value in the groovy script and then save it in a `TestCase` property you can use the follow code:

```
def idSession = context.expand('${test#Response#//ns1:authentification/bloc1/bloc2/idSession}')
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("propName",idSession)
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you very much, you're my savier  again :)